# I want to use the QComboBox with an Event (Return) in QT

Tags: c++, qt, qcombobox

I have the following problem:

I'm using the QComboBox of QT to select a path by a Drop & Down.
It is working fine after I choose one of the list, the path is automatically update. But now if I want to edit the Path manually by type in a path, I get immediately a warning. So I know that this is happening cause of the argument:

```
QComboBox::currentTextChanged
```

So always if I'm going to change the path, for example by changing only one letter or select it by Drop & Down the "currentTextChanged" and a new function will be called.
For example the function:

```
nextstep()
```

So what I want to achieve is that if I'm going to select a path the function should be called normally. But if I'm going to type in a new path or editing the path manually I want that the function will be called after type "return".

Comment: It would be nice if you'd provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subclass QComboBox and define a new signal in your class that's emitted only when the user types enter or when the index is changed.
To do that you must connect your new signal to `QComboBox::lineEdit()`'s `returnPressed()` or `editingFinished()` signals and to `QComboBox::currentIndexChanged()`.
I chose `editingFinished()` but you can try the other one too.
All that is left is to connect `nextstep()` to `currentTextSaved()`

To use `MyComboBox` in the `.ui` files, you have to promote the existing QComboBoxes to it.
Here's the official documentation: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-custom-widgets.html

mycombobox.h

```
#ifndef MYCOMBOBOX_H
#define MYCOMBOBOX_H

#include <QComboBox>

class MyComboBox : public QComboBox
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyComboBox(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

signals:
    void currentTextSaved(const QString &text);
};

#endif // MYCOMBOBOX_H
```

mycombobox.cpp

```
#include "mycombobox.h"

#include <QLineEdit>

MyComboBox::MyComboBox(QWidget *parent)
    : QComboBox(parent)
{
    connect(lineEdit(), &QLineEdit::editingFinished,
            this, [&] () { emit currentTextSaved(currentText()); });
    connect(this, QOverload<int>::of(&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged),
            this, [&] (int index) { Q_UNUSED(index) emit currentTextSaved(currentText()); });
}
```

Here's an example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sm1mszv9l2p9yqd/MyComboBox.zip?dl=0

This old post was useful https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/26860-Detecting-Enter-in-an-editable-QComboBox

Comment: thank you for the answer. I have now following problems: i can't use your second connect line. And what you mean with: All that is left is to connect nextstep() to currentTextSaved(). And how can i connect this steps with the ui. So actually i'm using following step: i use 'connect(ui.thecombbox, &QComboBox::currentTextChanged, this, &main::nextstep);.

Comment: @develop_96 Ops, I edited the answer this morning and I forgot one piece ;)

Comment: Usually `ui` is a pointer, so you'd have in the constructor, or in a `void setupUi()` method, of your class `connect(ui->myComboBox, &MyComboBox::currentTextSaved, this, &YourClass::yourSlot);`

Comment: yes right i'm using the ui like you said above. But now if i'm going to use the method &MyComboBox::currentTextSaved the connect doesn't work.

Comment: Jack Lilhammers
?

Comment: If you don't provide the code that's giving you issues it's hard to help you ;) Anyway I've added a minimal project to my answer. There's just a `MyComboBox` and a slot connected to `MyComboBox::currentTextSaved()` but it should be enough

Comment: Sorry, here the code where the problem occurs: connect(ui.thecombbox, &MyComboBox::currentTextSaved, this, &main::nextstep); i can't use connect after i use the connected slot to MyComboBox::currentTextSaved().

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your project I could be wrong, but I'd say that you're not connecting the right objects. `main`is a function, not an object, so I think you should use `&MainWindow::nextstep`. Also `ui` is a pointer, therefore you should dereference it like so `ui->thecombobox`

Comment: main is a class where my function nextstep is declared and implemented. My ui is not a pointer cause the connect function 'connect(ui.thecombbox, &QComboBox::currentTextChanged, this, &main::nextstep); is working fine. All your steps are working fine only the last one when i'm going to use MyComboBox::currentTextSaved() in connect() it say that "No instance of overloaded functions match the argument list".

Comment: What is the signature of nextstep()?

Comment: void main::nextstep()

Comment: This may be an issue for you now, but it's one of the best features of the connection syntax introduced with Qt5. Signals and slots must have compatible signatures and they're checked at compile time! You can look it up here https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html#signals-and-slots-with-default-arguments

Comment: In practice it means that nextstep must become `void nextstep(const QString &text)`

Comment: did your steps again :) but it doesn't work. same warning :/

Comment: My basic example on dropbox works, what are the differences? If the connection syntax is the same, I'm afraid I'll need to be able to reproduce your issue to help you. So you'll need to upload your code where I can see it

Comment: i tried your dropbox and it works so fine nice job. I try now to put the same on my project. There is only one Problem left: "&MyComboBox::currentTextSaved" it says: "A name followed by "::" must be a class or namespace name." I think if i solve this one it will works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228755/discussion-between-jack-lilhammers-and-develop-96).

Comment: Thank you for your help and effort Jack ! I finally solved it :)

Comment: You're welcome, but now I'm curious. What was it?